# creating a reverse image search code with python that searchs local files

Tags: python, image, search, python-requests

i have a database of images from telegram and i want to be able to reverse image search them i.e search local files.

i have tried using github libraries but none of them manage to do the reverse image search on local files.
i have also tried to use the requests library but failed to make a breakthrough so far.
i have seen people use the urls, but as im using scraped telegram data - i dont have the urls, only the jps themselves.

does anyone know of a way to do such a thing in python?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but consider using [Deep Image Search as seen on Github](https://github.com/TechyNilesh/DeepImageSearch). Here is also a tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znM_Z_jYT8E) - pretty straightforward and very easy to use reverse image search that is capable of using various image models, including Resnet50, which I use. You may try different models to achieve best results of your szenario.

I personally indexed over 70,000 local images (jpg) and can match a target image to receive X top results in a few milliseconds, ranked by similiarity. There are also ready to use handy local reverse image libraries that include a UI.

In short:

```
from DeepImageSearch import Load_Data, Search_Setup

# Load images from a folder
image_list = Load_Data().from_folder(['folder_path'])

# Set up the search engine, You can load 'vit_base_patch16_224_in21k',
'resnet50' etc more then 500+ models 
st = Search_Setup(image_list=image_list, model_name='vgg19',
pretrained=True, image_count=100)

# Index the images
st.run_index()

# Get metadata
metadata = st.get_image_metadata_file()

# Add new images to the index
st.add_images_to_index(['image_path_1', 'image_path_2'])

# Get similar images
st.get_similar_images(image_path='image_path', number_of_images=10)

# Plot similar images
st.plot_similar_images(image_path='image_path', number_of_images=9)

# Update metadata
metadata = st.get_image_metadata_file()
```